# personal onedrive is returning same id for drive and user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When reviewing some example OneDrive Items using Graph Explorer, it appears that the `user.id` and the `parentReference.driveId` are identical.  Is MSFT re-using one Id to identify both the `user` and `drive` object?

I have been testing my app against a number of OneDrive Business accounts and I do not believe I have seen this scenario.  I would like to understand if this is something specific to OneDrive Personal and/or what implications it might have...

I am not sure this will cause any issues, but my understanding was that all "IDs" were generally unique.

Here's a redacted snippet of JSON returned from Graph Explorer to illustrate what I am seeing:

```
{
    "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://xxx.yyy",
    "createdDateTime": "2018-12-04T19:02:41.173Z",
    "cTag": "aYzpDQjBCMTc0REJFRUY2RTU4ITMxNzEuMjI1",
    "eTag": "aQ0IwQjE3NERCRUVGNkU1OCEzMTcxLjk",
    "id": "<MY_USER_ID>!3171",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-12-04T19:10:36.83Z",
    "name": "blah-2018.docx",
    "size": 250538,
    "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/...",
    "createdBy": {
        "application": {
            "displayName": "MSOffice15",
            "id": "480728c5"
        },
        "device": {
            "id": "188000899fbcaf"
        },
        "user": {
            "displayName": "My Name",
            "id": "<MY_USER_ID>"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "application": {
            "displayName": "MSOffice15",
            "id": "480728c5"
        },
        "device": {
            "id": "188000899fbcaf"
        },
        "user": {
            "displayName": "My Name",
            "id": "<MY_USER_ID>"
        }
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "<MY_USER_ID>",
        "driveType": "personal",
        "id": "<MY_USER_ID>!109",
        "path": "/drive/root:"
    },
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "hashes": {
            "sha1Hash": "F0370F54348ED81F421EB036868AEBE5253AF58A"
        }
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2018-12-04T19:02:41.173Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-12-04T19:02:38.633Z"
    }
},
```

Note that `MY_USER_ID` is all uppercase in the prefix of the `driveItem.Id`.  It is all lowercase as my `driveId` and my `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive Personal isn't reusing the same id, it's using the User's Id as a prefix for Drive and DriveItem ids:

```
{User Id}!{OneDrive ID}
```

Since there is a 1:1 relationship between an MSA and it's Drive, there isn't much call for a more complex mechanism. OneDrive for Business, on the other hand, is hosted in SharePoint and, as such, use's SharePoint's identifiers. 
`

Comment: But it re-uses the id for UserID and DriveID.  They are identical, even though theoretically one is a User Object (with its associated metadata) and the other is a Drive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why that is an issue?

Comment: Well, as I said in my OP, I am trying to find out the facts, and I'm not sure this is an issue.  But, as a good example, if you're implementing a caching mechanism and using objects' ID as the key, you could run into trouble here (obviously depending upon the impl). Thanks for the feedback.